# Converting Javascript RegEx to C# Regex

Tags: javascript, c#, regex

I have a Javascript regex that tokenizes words from a sentence which is like the following:

`/\\[^]|\.+|\w+|[^\w\s]/g`

> Like if a sentence is entered like `Hello World.` the above regex will
>   tokenize it into words:
>
> `Hello`, `World`, `.`

I am trying to convert the above regex in C#, but its not able to group it. I have tried removing the `/` and the `\g` from the beginning and the end respectively, in order to make it compatible with .NET regex engine. But its still not working.

Below is the C# code I am trying:

```
public static void Main()
{
        string pattern = @"\\[^]|\.+|\w+|[^\w\s]";
        string input = @"hello world.";

        foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern, RegexOptions.ECMAScript))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("'{0}' found at index {1}.", m.Value, m.Index);
        }
}
```

Can anyone help me converting the above regex into C#?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that `RegexOptions.ECMAScript` just makes sure shorthand character classes (here, `\w` and `\s`) only match ASCII letters, digits and whitespace. You can't expect this option to "convert" the whole pattern for use in .NET regex library.

Here, `[^]` construct was used in JS regex to match any char. You may use `.` with a `RegexOptions.Singleline` option (and then you *will have to* remove the `RegexOptions.ECMAScript` option) instead of `[^]`, or just use `[\s\S]` to match any char:

```
public static void Main()
{
        string pattern = @"\\.|\.+|\w+|[^\w\s]";
        string input = @"hello world.";

        foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern,  RegexOptions.Singleline))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("'{0}' found at index {1}.", m.Value, m.Index);
        }
}
```

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/O12okF), its output:

```
'hello' found at index 0.
'world' found at index 6.
'.' found at index 11.
```

**NOTE**: `\w` and `\s` are Unicode aware in .NET regex, the match all Unicode letters with some diacritics, too. If you only want to handle ASCII, use

```
string pattern = @"\\.|\.+|[A-Za-z0-9_]+|[^A-Za-z0-9_\f\n\r\t\v\u00a0\u1680\u2000-\u200a\u2028\u2029\u202f\u205f\u3000\ufeff]";
```

**More details**

- [Word Character: **`\w`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-classes-in-regular-expressions#word-character-w)  in .NET regex
- [White-Space Character: **`\s`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-classes-in-regular-expressions#white-space-character-s) in .NET regex

Comment: Its not working, I am getting a `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.`

Comment: I did not check the code, but the regex is OK. Let me add a demo. [**Here is a C# demo**](https://ideone.com/O12okF)

Comment: Yeah, do I need to change my Regex to make it .NET compatible?

Comment: That depends on what your requirements are.

Comment: I want to tokenize the words in a sentence like in the question details using the .NET regex engine, In javascript I am able to do that correctly, but in C# i am not able to get any match

Comment: How will `\w` and `\s` get recognized by the .NET Regex engine?

Comment: To tokenize a *sentence like this*, you may use a *regex like the one you have*. It will work a bit differently now, as `\w` and `\s` are Unicode aware in .NET regex library. If you only want to handle ASCII, use `string pattern = @"\\.|\.+|[A-Za-z0-9_]+|[^A-Za-z0-9_\f\n\r\t\v\u00a0\u1680\u2000-\u200a\u2028\u2029\u202f\u205f\u3000\ufeff]";`

Comment: @KunalMukherjee I added two links to the MSDN pages where `\w` and `\s` are described.

Comment: I have a doubt, the regex tokenizes the numbers also. For e.g: To tokenize the utterance: `am i entitled for 0.5 day leave?` with the above regex gives: `'am' found at index 0.
' ' found at index 2.
'i' found at index 3.
' ' found at index 4.
'entitled' found at index 5.
' ' found at index 13.
'for' found at index 14.
' ' found at index 17.
'0' found at index 18.
'.' found at index 19.
'5' found at index 20.
' ' found at index 21.
'day' found at index 22.
' ' found at index 25.
'leave' found at index 26.
'?' found at index 31.
` Thereby tokenizing `0.5` also. How to avoid that?

Comment: @KunalMukherjee Try [this C# demo solution](https://ideone.com/j4SMrC). The `@"[-+]?\d*\.?\d+(\d[-+]?\d+)?|\w+|[^\w\s]"` pattern will tokenize into numbers, words and single punctuation/symbol chars.